# Parse weak ciphers out of an nmap.xml report

Tags: python, parsing

I wrote the following code to parse some weak ciphers out of an nmap.xml report. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to write this code in order to avoid the nested for loops with the double `if` loops. Also,  I had to create the two queues. There has to be a better way using list comprehension or a generator or something.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

md5Stack = []
shaStack = []
ip = []

with open('nmap.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
    for node in tree.getiterator('address'):
        ip = node.attrib.get('addr')
        for node in tree.getiterator('elem'):
            key = node.attrib.get('key')
            if key == "sha1" and ip not in shaStack:
                print ' %s :: %s' % (ip, key)
                shaStack += ip.split(",")
            if key == "md5" and ip not in md5Stack:
                print ' %s :: %s' % (ip, key)
                md5Stack += ip.split(",")
```

**Example XML**

```
<host starttime="1" endtime="1"><status state="up" reason="user-set" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="1.1.1.1" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<table key="pubkey">
<elem key="type">md5</elem>
<elem key="bits">56</elem>
</table>
<table key="validity">
<elem key="notBefore">00:00+00:00</elem>
<elem key="notAfter">:00:00+00:00</elem>
</table>
<elem key="md5">34lk5jl4k5jlk34j5lk34j5lk</elem>
<elem key="sha1">234lk6j23lk6j2l3kj32lk4j3l4</elem>
<elem key="pem">BEGIN CERTIFICATE;END CERTIFICATE;</elem>
</script></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="98" rttvar="4" to="2"/>
</host>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input XML so that we can see whether the way you extract information from the document is optimal?

Comment: FYI the DTD is at https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap.dtd

Comment: And I've found an example at https://github.com/cr0hn/golismero/blob/master/tests/test_nmap.xml

Comment: I added the XML to the original post. I am trying to get the IP address and the <elem key= values that have md5 or sha1. Note that it is heavily cut and obfuscated for obvious reasons. I still feel wrong even posting what I did lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that this does what you want, for a few reasons.

First, I'm not 100% on interleaving `ElementTree` iterators, but this may pick up more elements than you want; for example, what happens when the document is something like

```
<host>
<address addr="1.1.1.1"/>
</host>
<host>
<address addr="2.2.2.2"/>
<elem key="md5"/>
</host>
```

It's at least plausible to me that both IP addresses would show up in the md5 list. Even if it doesn't, you should strive to use code that has clear semantics.

Second, your filters check that `ip not in md5Stack` but what you add to `md5Stack` is `ip.split(',')`.

---

Let's try this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def extract_weak_ips(nmap_root):
    md5_ips = set()
    sha1_ips = set()
    hosts = list(nmap_root.iter('host'))
    for host in hosts:
        addresses = [address.get('addr').split(',') 
                     for address in host.findall(".//address[@addr]")]
        if host.find(".//elem[@key='md5']") is not None:
            md5_ips.update(addresses)
        if host.find(".//elem[@key='sha1']") is not None:
            sha1_ips.update(addresses)

def print_ip_set(s, key):
    for ip in s:
        print ' %s :: %s' % (ip, key)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ElementTree.XMLParser()
    parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
    md5_ips, sha1_ips = extract_weak_ips(ElementTree.parse('nmap.xml', parser).getroot())
    print_ip_set(md5_ips, 'md5')
    print_ip_set(sha1_ips, 'sha1')
```

I've extracted code into clear functions, and I'm using XPath queries so that the XML engine is doing the work of querying XML, not your application-specific code.

---

I think that in this case the list-comprehension approach is less readable than the code with for-loops, but if you really want list comprehensions, try this:

```
def extract_ips_with_key_type(nmap_root, key_type):
    query = ".//elem[@key='%s']" % key_type
    return set(apply(
        itertools.chain,
        (address.get('addr').split(',')
         for host in nmap_root.iter('host')
         if host.find(query) is not None
         for address in host.findall('.//address[@addr]')))
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your time! I'll work on the first example, right now I'm getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "testCase.py", line 20, in <module> md5_ips, sha1_ips = extract_weak_ips(ElementTree('nmapParseTest.xml','rt').getroot()) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Also I'm still doing research but I don't understand the following parts of your code: 1. what the ...set() is doing at the top. 2. What the hosts = list(nmap_root.iter('host'))is doing. And 3. What is the ".//elem[@key='md5']" doing exactly.

Comment: Oops, I had a typo -- I forgot the `parse` in `ElementTree.parse`. 1. The `set()` initializes the variables as `set`s, which are data structures that can't have multiple entries with the same value. 2. This is generating a list of `host` nodes: the structure of `nmap.xml` is a a bunch of `host` elements that have subelements including `address` and `elem`. 3. That is an XPath query that finds sub-elements of the current element with tag `elem` and attribute `key` with value `'md5'`.

Comment: Dude thank you so much for taking your time and explaining that. You are very much appreciated.

Comment: Now I am getting the following error that I think may be a bug in ElementTree:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testCase.py", line 20, in <module>
    md5_ips, sha1_ips = extract_weak_ips(ElementTree.parse('nmapParseTest.xml', 'rt').getroot())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1183, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'feed'

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237466/python-elementtree-support-for-parsing-unknown-xml-entities. You have to enable UseForeignDTD.

Comment: So I need to build a parser object and set the UseForeignDTD attribute to true? This would require a redesign right? Thank you for the link.

Comment: No, not a full redesign; in fact, I've edited my post to do that (it still won't work on the snippet you've given because there's a couple stray tags in there: `</script></port></ports>`